# How to convert a panda series to a time series?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to extract data from MYSQL server and making a dataframe out of it.The SQL query I use is

```
sql="""SELECT dp.Date, dp.Open , dp.High, dp.Low, dp.Close, dp.Volume, dp.Adj 
     FROM tickers AS tick
     INNER JOIN daily_price AS dp
     ON dp.ticker_id = tick.id
     WHERE tick.ticker = '%s'
     ORDER BY dp.Date ASC;"""%(ticker)
goog = psql.frame_query(sql, con=con, index_col='Date')
```

This is working perfectly fine but when I use the function `df=obtain_df(ticker)` (`obtain_df` is just the function to get the `dataframe`) and use `type(df['High'])` it `panda.series` and not as `timeseries`? I don't know the reason for this. In my SQL server also date is in the format 'DATE'.

Can you suggest how I convert the series to timeseries ?

```
da['Date']=pd.DatetimeIndex(da['Date'])

da.set_index('Date')

print da.head()
```

I get the following output[image]

How do i make the date column as index.

Comment: Give some data from `dataframe` as example.

Comment: What format is your data in at the moment? You can test this with `df['Date'].dtype`

Comment: df['Date'].dtype gives it as a object so how do i change to date

Comment: Data of Dataframe are downloaded from yahoo OHLCV data for a stock

Comment: it says series object has no .to_datetime attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 df['Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
```

or:

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

If you have `datetime` in unusual format:

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d%m%Y")
```

Comment: I used the first one, and it did work but know it is not able to set me date as index,for more info look in my edits in the question

Comment: `da.set_index( da['Date'] )`